# What semantic notions underlie PIE *meh₂d- ('wet') and Proto-Germanic *matōną, *matjaną (“to feed, eat”)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, proto-germanic

I was reading the etymology of [*amadouer*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amadouer#Etymology) when I lighted on these attested morphemes:

> Etymology
>
> From [Middle French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French) *[amadouer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amadouer#Middle_French)* (“to coax, lure”), from *[a-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-#Middle_French)* + **madouer* (“to lure, give food to”), from [Old Norse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse) *[mata](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mata#Old_Norse)* (“to lure, feed”), from [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*matōną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/mat%C5%8Dn%C4%85)*, *[*matjaną](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/matjan%C4%85)* (“to feed, eat”), from [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) *[*meh₂d-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/meh%E2%82%82d-#Proto-Indo-European-wet)* (“wet”). Cognate with [Icelandic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_language) *[mata](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mata#Icelandic)* (“to bait, allure”), [Danish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_language) *[made](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/made#Danish)* (“to feed”), [Gothic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_language)  ([matjan](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matjan#Gothic), “to eat, have a meal”), [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) *[mete](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mete#Old_English)* (“food”). More at [meat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meat#English).

1. Please see the titled question. How did **meh₂d-*  semantically shift to mean **matōną*? What does eating or feeding have to do with wetness? I know that people drink while eating, but I'd reckon that PIE and Proto-Germanic had verbs for drinking?
2. Which [type of semantic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change#Typology_by_Blank_(1999)) is this?

Comment: Animals have to get fat before long journeys, read "trans-saharan trade". We talk of *juicy* beef after all.

Comment: the root of *to eat* is very close and it is very very basic. *ma* is still a frequent colloquial particle, seemingly from *X-mal*, x-times, i.e. *at once, at this suitable time* but *mir* "me, to me" as used in selfreflexive verbs may be hidden in it. *Messe* "mass" also comes to mind (cp. Lat Vesper, whence Ger. *Vesper*, "brunch"). Also, *Mahlzeit* "meal-time"

Comment: Cp. *meadow*, *grass* and *graze*.

Comment: *mead*, Ger. *Most* (honey wine, cider) vs *Mast, mästen*, "to stuff up, (transitive) gain mass", vs *Matsch, Modder, modern* "pulp, slime", *Maische* "the medium in beer brewing": We sy *ansätzen* (on-set) either about fat accumulating, or about setting up a brew, a stew, etc (which may get thick due to yeast), and various other ways. Soup is eaten as well as slurped (*Suppe schlürfen); Eating noisily with the mouth open is *schmatzen* (so as to drool? Close to *Schmutz*, *smut*? Observe s-mobile; Cp. *schlämmen* to *slime* as *schlummern, lummern* to *slumber*, *limb*; Is soup *slim* stew?).

Comment: Also *soup* vs *saufen* (to drink like an animal, also of alcohol); *supper*; Cp. *sober* and that *[in]ebriated* is somewhat uncertain, the root being a-typical. I do suspect a relation to sabbath (rest). I mean I see it and *salat* "prayer*, *salam* "peace" e-ver-y-where. Just cp *lavo* ~ *labo* to *sich laben*.

Comment: cp. *Urlaub* "leave, vacation, holliday", *Feierabend* to get a guess at what I mean.

Comment: On The Other Hand: Compare *sweat* "to lose moisture", Ger. *Mehl-Schwitze* "a reduced flour sauce", versus *wet*. It would make some limited sense to suppose that \*(s) means "out" and \*m- means "in, into", or rather \*n-, cp. Ger. *ge-nießen*. I am not seeing clearly; I thought for a moment that \*(s)w-d- and \*meh2d compared wonderfully to *sweet* and *salty*, but I should have meant something with an *m*. T *malt*? *Schmalz*, which salted? *schmelzen*, *melt*; \*gel- "cold", vs *galact-*, "milk"? Greek *almyros*, "salty", Hebrew *melak*, "salt"??? *Alemania*! Sorry.

Comment: Very obviously, salt and sweat water bodies come to mind. Since I'd compare sabbath to easter (cp. Russian "easter", Turkey "sunday") and the east, and since seas and the directions of the sky were called by colors, ... I don't know. I'd guess the dead sea was the white sea? But the medditerreaenian etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kroonen's dictionary says, following [Lubotsky (1981)]

> *matjan- w.v. 'to lap' -- [...] In spite of Torp 1909: 305 
>   and Pokorny IEW: 694-5, unrelated to *mati- 'food' (q.v.)."

The only Germanic reflex given is an old Norse term "to suckle, nurse", agreeing with Albanian evidence and agreeing not so much with the semantics in Sanskrit "to rejoice" in relation to intoxication," and Greek "to drip, melt, ...".

They reconstruct respectively PIE *mh2-d- and tentatively *med-; The later is found in wiktionary under "measure".

*mati- has more explanation. I am not going to quote the whole thing, if I only understand half of it. Follow the sources (Lubotsky 2012 also has some on water):

- Lubotsky, A.M. 1981 [Lubotsky 1981] 
  *Gr. πήγνῡμι: Skt. pajra- and loss of laryngeals before mediae in Indo-Iranian*. Münchener Studien zur Sprachwissenschaft 40, 133-138
- Pokorny, J. 1959 [Pokorny IEW] 
  *Indogermanisches etymologisches Worterbuch*. Bern.
- Torp, A. 1909 [Torp 1909) 
  *Wortschatz der germanischen Spracheinheit*. Vierte Auflage. Göttingen.